# MON_GET_DATABASE function in DB2

Tags: database, db2

I am using the MON_GET_DATABASE function in DB2. I am using this connection to get data from multiple database. Does this function support cross-database access like SNAP_GET_DB?

I am using the query as
SELECT * FROM TABLE(MON_GET_DATABASE(-2)) AS CONNECTION_DETAILS; It returns only the details of the single database that I am currently connected to. Earlier we were using SNAP_GET_DB (now deprecated), which used to fetch the details of all the database available for connection. Is there anything additional thing to be done to get details of all the database while using MON_GET_DATABASE(-2) function?

Comment: I removed db2-400 tag because DB2 for IBM i does not have MON_GET_DATABASE. Maybe db2-luw ?

Comment: All the MON_GET_* functions are for the currently connected database, including MON_GET_DATABASE (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-mon-get-database-get-database-metrics). AFAIK this is one of the drawbacks of that type of interface (there are many benefits).

Comment: @data_henrik Thanks for the info. Is there any alternative for it to get details for all the DB?  SNAP_GET_DB used to fetch all the DB details but it is deprecated now.

Comment: @hellokk  Either use the (still working but deprecated) `snap_get_db` , or __workaround__ via iterating over the active databases on the member and using the mon_get_db per database-name. Some MON_GET% routines accept a DB_NAME argument that can be NULL to indicate they should return all active databases names, such as mon_get_memory_pool,  mon_get_memory_set and a few others.  You could loop on those db_names returned, calling mon_get_db on each.